# Make d3.js file get data from mongoDB server

Tags: python, html, mongodb, csv, d3.js

I have a d3.js file that creates a histogram  from data in a csv file. The csv file is obtained from a pymongo code snippet. Is there any way I can make the html file(d3.js) to get data directly from the mongodb server? Thanks!

Comment: Is this mongodb server reachable from a url? Like "/getMyCsvFile"

Comment: No. I use a port number and host to extract it. I used cmd for it.

Comment: @echonax Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for trying man!

Comment: Do you know someone who does?